# gcloud asking enable services, and not running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Weird issue while using google sdk. I m getting following errors. It has been already enabled Compute API. I tried with it different computers. It 's the same.

```
gcloud compute instances create test-instance
```

**API [compute.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [xxxxxxxxx]. Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? (y/N)?  y**

**Enabling service [compute.googleapis.com] on project [xxxxxxxxx]...
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Retry
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.**

Comment: Try enabling the service in the Google Cloud Console web GUI. You can check for enabled services with `gcloud services list --enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue while working on Mac then I just reinstalled the sdk and restarted and it was working fine. Worth giving  it a try. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the sdk and try running gcloud auth and restart your machine once. Hopefully this should go away.
Happy learning .